# How can you view Obj files in Visual Studio as text instead of the 3D Renderer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio, obj files display in a nifty 3D renderer, as seen below.

[image]

The problem is, I can't figure out how to view the text of the obj file without opening it up in an external editor. Is there a way to switch between the rendered mode and text mode for graphic programmers?

Comment: Right click the file, `Open With...`, then select the text editor. Have fun.

Comment: That was WAY too obvious. Thank you. Make it an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio 'Tools / Options / Text Editor / Extensions / Add Extension:  (OBJ, Visual Studio C++)
Then every .obj will open as a text file.